# Getting substring by index position

Tags: grep

i need to extract a substring from a line using the initial and final position. I think it should be easily done with grep, but still haven't figured out how.

An example, a line of n chars, i want to extract the substring starting at k position and ending in the l position of that line.

With obviously l, k < n and l > k

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not use [awk](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~oostr102/docs/nawk/nawk_92.html)?

```
echo "12345678" | awk '{print substr($0, 3, 2);}'
# prints '34'
```

Comment: You're welcome. `awk` will apply this to each line in the file. I don't know how you wanted to manage files or input with multiple lines. You can do a lot more with `awk` if you search.

Answer (score 8):

Cut is a good choice for this. You can select ranges and individual fields:

```
$ echo "123456" | cut -c2-4
234

$ echo "123456" | cut -c1,3,6
136

$ echo "123456" | cut -c1-3,6
1236
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using bash you could just do:

```
LINE="strings"
K=3  ## 4th character starting from index 0
L=5  ## 6th character starting from index 0
echo "${LINE:K:L - K + 1}"
```

On a loop for a file:

```
while -r read LINE; do echo "${LINE:K - 1:L - K}"; done < file
```

As for awk basing that L means the position and not the length where 0 is the starting index:

```
awk -v k="3" -v l="5" '{ n = length; print substr($0, k, l - k + 1);}' < file
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [sed](/questions/tagged/sed):

```
k=3
echo '123456789' | sed 's/^.\{'$k'\}//'
```

*Output:*

```
456789
```

Answer (score -2):

Is this what your looking for?

```
    String test = "ateststring";
    String testa = test.substring(0,4);
    String test2 = testa.substring(0,3);
    int testc = test.indexOf("test");
    String test3 = test.substring(testc,5);

    System.out.println(test + ":" + testa + ":" + test2 + ":" +test3);
```